# Revoking BigQuery Authorized View access through DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have granted access to Authorized view in BiqQuery via DBT using the following method

```
  {{ config (
       grant_access_to=[{'project': 'project_1', 'dataset': 'dataset_1'}]
       )
  }}

SELECT * FROM `project_1.dataset_2.view_1`
```

For granting access, it works. However, I can't find a way to revoke the access via DBT or SQL (or DCL/ DDL).

How can I revoke or remove access to the authorized view using DBT?

Comment: Not too familiar with DBT, but since it is  an external access to bq you could have different credentials to manage this permissions, I mean a different Service account

Comment: The connection is already using a service account. This is more towards how to implement https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-revoke-dataset-access#bigquery_revoke_dataset_access-python as a SQL command so that I can call that in Dbt.

Comment: Hi @Avi I am not sure how you will do it via DBT but in BigQuery using [REVOKE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-control-language#revoke_statement) DCL statement it is very much possible . Did you checked these documentations [Revoking access to a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#revoking_access_to_a_dataset) and [Update an access policy on a table or view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#update_an_access_policy)

Comment: Hi @SayanBhattacharya thank you. I did check those. For the revoke, I can't figure out what user_list the view can be. I am not assigning to a user directly, I am authorising view. The same goes for roles. What is the equivalent role of AccessEntry? Same for the access. It requires an API call to get values in dict, and update entire dict minus the view. Is there a SQL equivalent that you know of?

Comment: @Avi [user_list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-control-language#user_list) is nothing but normal users,service accounts,goggle groups etc.In your case my best guess is you have to revoke permissions of the service account you are using for connection. As for  AccessEntry,  these are the basic [required permission to query tables and views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#required_permission_to_query_tables_and_views).[`Revoke example`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-control-language#example_2)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at this moment we can't do it using Dbt because revoking just that view from the dataset can't be done using SQL / DDL in bigquery. Current process is:

1. call the dataset,
2. get the whole list of views
3. and remove just that
4. view update the dataset.

I can see that done via API calls in Python from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-revoke-dataset-access

I have added this as a comment here https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery/issues/198#issuecomment-1176975145